# JavaFX CSS incompatibility

Tags: java, css, javafx

Disclaimer: I'm very new to CSS.

I am attempting to draw a box with a shadow, using css, in a Java application using JavaFX. I used [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7foctpm1/1/) to verify that the CSS was doing what I wanted, and once I'd gotten everything perfect I went and inserted that into the stylesheet I'm using for the object I'm trying to draw.

Here's the Original CSS:

```
.tallBox {
    width: 30px;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #00AA00;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px #008800,
                2px 2px #008800,
                3px 3px #008800,
                4px 4px #008800;
}
```

And here's the CSS I tried using in JavaFX:

```
.tallBox {
    -fx-min-width: 30px;
    -fx-max-width: 30px;
    -fx-min-height: 90px;
    -fx-max-height: 90px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #00AA00;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px #008800,
                2px 2px #008800,
                3px 3px #008800,
                4px 4px #008800;
}
```

Java complained about `box-shadow` only taking a list of `<size>` as arguments, so I split it into `box-shadow` and `box-shadow-color` as below:

```
.tallBox {
    -fx-min-width: 30px;
    -fx-max-width: 30px;
    -fx-min-height: 90px;
    -fx-max-height: 90px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #00AA00;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px,
                2px 2px,
                3px 3px,
                4px 4px;
    box-shadow-color: #008800;
}
```

This stopped java from complaining, but nothing is being displayed, and JSFiddle doesn't accept the box-shadow arguments in the new format.

Does anyone know how to correctly do this in JavaFX?

**Edit**: I developed my CSS based on [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29661696/6112457).

Comment: "JavaFX CSS" is similar to "HTML CSS", but the properties are very different, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html

Answer (score 3):

I think what you need is `-fx-effect: dropshadow(<blur-type>, <color>, <number1>, <number2>, <number3>, <number4>)`, for example:

```
.tallBox {
<other properties>
-fx-effect: dropshadow( gaussian , rgba(255,255,255,0.5) , 0,0,0,1 );
}
```

Here the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) that explains everything a little better but in essence:

- **blur-type** = [ gaussian | one-pass-box | three-pass-box | two-pass-box ]
- **color** The shadow Color
- **number1** The radius of the shadow blur kernel. In the range [0.0 ... 127.0], typical value 10.
- **number2** The spread of the shadow. The spread is the portion of the radius where the contribution of the source material will be 100%. The remaining portion of the radius will have a contribution controlled by the blur kernel. A spread of 0.0 will result in a distribution of the shadow determined entirely by the blur algorithm. A spread of 1.0 will result in a solid growth outward of the source material opacity to the limit of the radius with a very sharp cutoff to transparency at the radius. Values should be in the range [0.0 ... 1.0].
- **number3** The shadow offset in the x direction, in pixels.
- **number4** The shadow offset in the y direction, in pixels

For a short tutorial-type article, see [here](http://www.dummies.com/programming/java/javafx-how-to-add-shadows/).

Comment: Hmmm, I'm actually not intending to get an effect that looks like a shadow, but rather using the 'box shadow' to draw a rectangle under the image.