# <mat-card> is not raised - there is no border

Tags: css, angular-material2, angular5

I have this simple html:

```
 <mat-card>
    <mat-card-content>
      <code>{{file}}</code>
    </mat-card-content>
 </mat-card>
```

for some reason when the mat-card element is rendered, it's not raised -  I am looking to get something like this:

[image]

does anyone know if I might be missing some additional CSS? I don't get it.

Comment: you probably just need a margin, do something like mat-card{ margin:2em;}

Comment: but is mat-card the class? how can I add the right css? pretty newb here

Comment: looks like they moved it - https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1325

Comment: no it is the html element. you can also  do it using a class or id

Comment: so something like `(style)={ margin:2em;}`?

Comment: style="margin:2em;" but I may be wrong cause I may not get your question completely

Comment: I think you have it right

Comment: you can see this https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-card-niel?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: thanks yeah I added an answer, I owe you

Comment: your welcome. I just added my answer hehe for completeness.

Comment: Can you just mark my answer as the solution? Thanks!

Comment: np happy to do that thanks for returning the favor :)

Comment: you're awesome!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably just need a margin in your mat-card.

```
<mat-card style="margin:2em;">
...more code
</mat-card>
```

Here's a stackblitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-so-mat-card-not-raised?file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: I also had to add:

`border: 1px solid;
box-shadow: -1px 1px #77aaff, -2px 2px #77aaff, -3px 3px #77aaff, -4px 4px #77aaff, -5px 5px #77aaff; `

per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620239/css-whats-a-good-way-to-create-a-raised-box-effect

Comment: @jones-chris have you checked this https://material.angular.io/guide/elevation, you can also use the class `mat-elevation-z[0-24]` so adding another css like above might not be necessary

Comment: No, I haven't.  Thanks for mentioning it!  I'll give it a try :).

Comment: My issue was that I did not have the @import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css'; in my style.css

Comment: i can't avoid not saying thanks and just upvoting.. i tried my best.. i would never think it's margin related and i tried to change my custom theme and got confused.. so  thanks a lot!

Answer (score 15):

My issue was that I didnt have a theme imported in my styles.css:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

Comment: despite angular CLI asking you what style you want it needed setting manually for me ...

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add a margin to the mat-card, so maybe

```
@Component({
  styles: [`

  mat-card { margin:2em;  }

  `]
})
```

Comment: yep this worked.. Why this is not the default css, is beyond me

Comment: There's an issue for it stating that it is up to the developer to implement margins: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1325

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented a custom theme, make sure a parent of your `mat-card` has this theme applied. This will typically be the app root.

My custom theme is `rr-theme-light` - so I had to add this class to a parent of `mat-card` in order to get the shadow to appear at all.

[image]